# Only return rows from a dataframe which match criteria in two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe from which I want to return only the rows in which the values in column `'1'` match a specific string and in column `'2'` the value is an integer.

I have the following code in which I attempt to generate a set of indexes which match the criteria and then only pull these rows through from the dataframe.

```
Ok_index = df[(df['1']== "string") & (df['2'] % 1 == 0)].index

new_df = df.iloc[Ok_index]
```

I understand the issue will be with the second conditional statement but I don't know how to apply the same logic from the string check to the integer check.

The following dataframe:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'String' | 1.5 |
| 'String' | 10 |
| 'Not string' | 10 |

Should return this dataframe:

| 1 | 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 'String' | 10 |

Comment: May you provide a reproducible example of your dataframe and expected output.

Comment: Try this ```df_filtered = df[(df.1 == 'string') & (df.2 % 1 ==0)]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with `is_integer`

```
df['2'].apply(lambda x : x.is_integer())
0    False
1     True
2     True
Name: 2, dtype: bool
```

Comment: @jezrael sure ~

Comment: If in future similar problem, let me know, I really like vote for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Actually your error is in your second line. You are retrieving the `index` from the dataframe, so you need to use `.loc` in order to filter it. Essentialy:

```
new_df = df.loc[Ok_index]
```

But if you want to use all pandas' power, you can actually do all this in a single line:

```
new_df = df[(df['1']== "string") & (df['2'] % 1 == 0)]
```

You don't need to get the `index` for the desirable rows first, and then filter the dataframe. You can do all this at once.